# "Error: read ECONNRESET" on Node-RED when writing to InfluxDB

Tags: node.js, influxdb, node-red

I have just started with Node-RED and InfluxDB, and I would like to apologise if this is a very silly question.

There was a network disconnection on my server earlier - after reconnecting the server back to the network, the error **Error: read ECONNRESET** is frequently showing whenever receiving an MQTT signal and trying to write it into influxdb.

A little bit of the background on my work - I am working on an Industrial IoT project, where each machines will send in signals via MQTT to Node-RED, get processed in Node-RED and log into influxDB. The code has been running without issue before the network disconnection, and I have seen other posts stating that restarting Node-RED would solve the problem - but I cannot afford to restart it unless schedule a time with the factory - till then, more data will be loss.

`"Error: read ECONNRESET"`

[image: Error showing in debug that comes from the InfluxDB nodes]

This error is happening at many different influxdb nodes - not a single specific incident. Is there anyway to resolve this without having to restart Node-RED?

[image: Properties in influxdb nodes]

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Given that it's not storing any data at the moment, I would say take the hit and restart Node-RED as soon as possible.

The other option is if you are on a recent Node-RED release is to just restart the flow. You can do this from the bottom of the drop down menu on the Deploy button. This will leave Node-RED running and just stop all the nodes and restart them. This will be quicker than a full restart.

I assume you are using the [node-red-contrib-influxdb](https://flows.nodered.org/node/node-red-contrib-influxdb) node. It looks to be using the [Influx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/influx) npm node under the covers. I can't see anything obvious in the doc about configuring it to reconnect in case of a failure with the database. I suggest you set up a test system and then try and reproduce this by restarting the DB, if you can then you can open an issue with the node-red-contrib-influxdb on github and see if they can work out how to get it to reconnect after a failure.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I have tried to restart the flow by using the second option that you have provided, yet this issue is still there. I am not sure whether is this issue caused by the number of data that I put into InfluxDB at once, as sometimes it would work (I can see new data coming in InfluxDB) yet sometimes it shows this error.

Answer (score 0):

There was a power outage one day and have restarted the whole system. Now the database is working fine. It worked, and I didn't know why. Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a similar issue where the Victron Node-Red module makes TCP calls to DBUS on a CCGX host. Node-Red appears to hang. After looking at a network trace it seems like there's a DNS problem. I just updated the TCP host to use an IP address rather than a FQDN and it's been stable ever since.